# Splash screen Android App has stopped

Tags: android, splash-screen

I want to make a splash screen for my android app. I have written following codes in welcomescreen.java in android studio. But after running the app, the app has stopped. :( What shall I Do now?

```
package com.mateors.welcomescreen;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class WelcomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome_screen);
    Thread myThread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(5000);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };
    myThread.start();
}
}
```

Comment: What is you error in log cat?

Comment: Let me guess ,You forgot to declare MainActivity in your manifest ?.

Comment: No I have declared that

Comment: Then please post your logcat ..We cannot guess what error you are getting..

Comment: can you post the error

Comment: I think you forgot in manifest <intent-filter> in Splash activity and after <intent-filter> add this line  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

Answer (score 3):

```
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 1500;
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);


            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent i = new Intent(WelcomeScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
        }
```

try the above code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code:

```
package com.mateors.welcomescreen;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class WelcomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 5000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome_screen);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(WelcomeScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
}
```